# Java OpenGL window closes as soon as it opens

Tags: java, maven, opengl, jogl

I'm using maven to import the jogamp dependencies.

Here is the pom.xml content :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The code below should create a window.

```
import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;

public class Renderer {

    private static GLWindow window = null;

    public static void init(){
        GLProfile.initSingleton();
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(profile);

        window = GLWindow.create(caps);
        window.setSize(640, 360);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        init();
    }
}
```

In my case, it creates a window that closes as soon as it opens, and it says `Process finished with exit code 0`. I followed [these instructions](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Maven), but even by adding the joal and jocl support into maven it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [FPSAnimator](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/FPSAnimator.html)

```
public static void init(){
        GLProfile.initSingleton();
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(profile);

        window = GLWindow.create(caps);
        window.setSize(640, 360);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
        FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(window, 30);
        animator.start();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ! It is strange that the window closes without FPSAnimator, but it works now anyway. :)